# Using PIVOT for dates to convert into MTD,QTD,YTD

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have a table which looks something like below

```
    Dates Start Date End    Code    Type    Values
    Jan-14  Dec-14  AccountCode A1  0.005
    Oct-14  Dec-14  AccountCode A1  0.001
    Dec-14  Dec-14  AccountCode A1  0.0017
    Jan-14  Dec-14  AccountCode A2  -0.004832912
    Oct-14  Dec-14  AccountCode A2  -0.002195574
    Dec-14  Dec-14  AccountCode A2  -0.001396166
```

Need to write a query where I can convert using pivot to

```
displayperiod   A1          A2
YTD            0.005    -0.004832912
QTD            0.001    -0.002195574
MTD            0.0017   -0.001396166
```

I am currently stuck in converting the dates to YTD ,MTD and QTD .

Any help is highly appreciated.

********************Adding more Data items
Data for Jan

```
        SELECT * FROM mytable
        WHERE   
        AND data_enddate = '20140131' 
        ORDER BY type, data_startdate 

        Output from table

        data_startdate  data_enddate    factor_name value
        1/1/2014    1/31/2014   A1  0.0018  
        1/1/2014    1/31/2014   A2  0.0024 

        In this case MTD = YTD = QTD

        hence the output required

        displayperiod   A1          A2
        YTD            0.0018    0.002
        QTD            0.0018    0.002
        MTD            0.0018   0.002
```

Data for Feb

```
        SELECT * FROM mytable
        WHERE   
        AND data_enddate = '20140228' 
        ORDER BY type, data_startdate 

        Output from table

        data_startdate  data_enddate    factor_name value
        1/1/2014        2014-02-28      A1  0.0011  
        1/2/2014        2014-02-28      A1  0.0024 
        1/1/2014        2014-02-28      A2  0.0021  
        1/2/2014        2014-02-28      A2  0.0034 

        In this case MTD = QTD ,YTD 

        hence the output required

        displayperiod   A1          A2
        YTD            0.0024    0.0034
        QTD            0.0011    0.0021
        MTD            0.0011    0.0021
```

Data for Mar

```
        SELECT * FROM mytable
        WHERE   
        AND data_enddate = '20140331' 
        ORDER BY type, data_startdate 

        Output from table

        data_startdate  data_enddate    factor_name value
        1/1/2014        2014-03-31      A1  0.0011  
        1/3/2014        2014-03-31      A1  0.0024 
        1/1/2014        2014-02-28      A2  0.0021  
        1/2/2014        2014-02-28      A2  0.0034
```

In this case MTD , QTD=YTD

```
        hence the output required

        displayperiod   A1          A2
        YTD            0.0011    0.0021
        QTD            0.0011    0.0021
        MTD            0.0024    0.0034
```

Data for Apr

```
            SELECT * FROM mytable
            WHERE   
            AND data_enddate = '2014-04-30' 
            ORDER BY type, data_startdate 

            Output from table

            data_startdate  data_enddate    factor_name value
            1/1/2014        2014-04-30      A1  0.0011  
            1/4/2014        2014-04-30      A1  0.0024 
            1/1/2014        2014-04-30      A2  0.0021  
            1/4/2014        2014-04-30      A2  0.0034 

            In this case MTD , QTD=YTD 

            hence the output required

            displayperiod   A1          A2
            YTD            0.0011    0.0021
            QTD            0.0011    0.0021
            MTD            0.0024    0.0034
```

Data for May

```
            SELECT * FROM mytable
            WHERE   
            AND data_enddate = '2014-04-30' 
            ORDER BY type, data_startdate 

            Output from table

            data_startdate  data_enddate    factor_name value
            1/1/2014        2014-05-31      A1  0.0011  
            1/4/2014        2014-05-31      A1  0.0024 
            1/5/2014        2014-05-31      A1  0.0030
            1/1/2014        2014-05-31      A2  0.0021  
            1/4/2014        2014-05-31      A2  0.0034 
            1/5/2014        2014-05-31      A2  0.0032 

            In this case MTD , QTD,YTD 

            hence the output required

            displayperiod   A1          A2
            YTD            0.0011    0.0021
            QTD            0.0024    0.0034
            MTD            0.0030    0.0032
```

Data for June

June will have 3 rows

data for July

July will have 2 rows where MTD = QTD and separate YTD

Data for Aug

AUG will have 2 rows where MTD = QTD and separate YTD

Data for Sept
SEPt will have 3 rows

Data for Oct
Oct will have 2 rows where MTD = QTD and separate YTD

Data for NOV

Nov will have 3 rows

data for DEC

Dec will have 3 rows

Comment: Where is your version of the code?

Answer (score 2):

Find the `month` difference between `start` and `end` date in `pivot` source query to get the `displayperiod` using `case` statement. Try this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Cast('01-' + Dates_Start AS DATE) Date_Start,
                Cast('01-' + Date_End AS DATE)    Date_End,
                code,type,value
         FROM   yourtable)
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Datediff(mm, Date_Start, Date_End) + 1 = 12 THEN 'YTD'
         WHEN Datediff(mm, Date_Start, Date_End) + 1 = 3 THEN 'QTD'
         WHEN Datediff(mm, Date_Start, Date_End) + 1 = 1 THEN 'MTD'
       END AS displayperiod,
       [A1],
       [A2]
FROM   cte
       PIVOT (Max(value)
             FOR type IN ([A1],
                          [A2]))pv
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1fbcb/1)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.The data in my table contains mtd,QTD and YTD and this data will be populated for every month differently

For Eg: JAN 1 row so MTD = YTD = QTD
Feb 2 row so MTD and QTD = YTD
Mar 2 row so MTD and QTD = YTD
April 2 row so MTD and QTD = YTD
MAY 3 row so MTD,QTD,YTD
JUNE 3 row so MTD,QTD,YTD
JULY 2 row so MTD and QTD = YTD
AUG 3 row so MTD,QTD,YTD
SEP 3 row so MTD,QTD,YTD
OCT 2 row so MTD and QTD = YTD
NOV 3 row so MTD,QTD,YTD
DEC 3 row so MTD,QTD,YTD

Comment: @user1143726 - So whats the problem

Comment: the problem is that number of rows present in the table will be different every month because of above logic I have shared .therefore I need to built one query based on above logic so that I get YTD,MTD,QTD everytime.Thanks again

Comment: @user1143726 - can add some sample data and expected output of your problem am not completely clear

Comment: I have added sample data in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

It worked here is the answer

```
                    SELECT * INTO #temp FROM (
                     SELECT startdate  ,
                                    endate ,
                                    factor_name,contribution
                             FROM   myTable WHERE account_code = 'myaccount'  and endate = '20140228' AND startdate IN ( SELECT
                       DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,'20140228'), 0) AS StartOfYear)

                       UNION ALL

                        SELECT startdate  ,
                                    endate ,
                                    factor_name,contribution
                             FROM   myTable WHERE account_code = 'myaccount'  and endate = '20140228' AND startdate IN ( 
                    SELECT   
                        DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, '20140228'), 0) )


                       UNION ALL 

                        SELECT startdate  ,
                                    endate ,
                                    factor_name,contribution
                             FROM   myTable WHERE account_code = 'myaccount'  and endate = '20140228' AND startdate IN (SELECT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, '20140228'), 0) )

                             ) AS tmp
```